# Set of points with bounded orbit is closed

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, transformation, group-actions, automorphism-group

Let $T:X\to X$ be a homeomorphism of a topological Hausdorff space $X$. $T$ induces an action of the integers on $Homeo(X)$ by $n\mapsto T^n$. 
Let $orb(x)=\{T^n(x): x\in X\}$.
Fix $N\in\mathbb{N}$. I want to look on a subset of $X$ which is all the points of orbit at most $N$, i.e. $X_{\leq N}=\{x\in X: |orb(x)|\leq N\}$.

Why $X_{\leq N}$ is a closed subset of $X$?

Thoughts: it is enough to show that points with orbit exactly $k$, where $0\leq k\leq N$, is a closed subset. Then $X_{\leq N}$ is a finite union of those.
For example, if I want to show that $X_{=2}$ is closed then it does not necessarily coincide with the set of points of period $2$, i.e. $T^2(x)=x$, because those can have orbits of length $3$: $\{T^{-1}(x), x, T(x)\}$ and it does not intersect with points of period $1$, because they all have orbits of length $1$. So how can I describe it in terms of periodicity?

Comment: Yes, Thanks! I edited the question

Comment: What you want to show isn't true. Consider $X=[-1,1]$ and $T(x)=-x$.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks for the comment. Then, I agree that my approach would not work. But still in this case $X_{\leq 1}=\{0\}$ and $X_{\leq 2}=X$ so they are both closed in $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \in X_{\leq N}$ if and only if $T^{k}(x)=x$ for some $k \in {1,2,...,N}$. So $X_{\leq N}$ is the union of the closed sets $\{x:T^{k}(x)=k\}$ over $k\leq N$.

Comment: Intersection, not union?  And rather $\{x: T^k(x) = x\}$?

Comment: okay, I see now that my intuition of $T^2(x)=x$ can lead to orbit $\{T^{-1}(x),x,T(x)\}$ of length $3$ is clearly wrong.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want the union. Intersection would be the set of fixed points.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is first  countable:
Let $x_n \in X_{\leq N}$ be a sequence converging to a point $x$. $T$ is a homeomorphism so for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ $T^k(x_n)\to T^k(x)$. There are at most $N$ distinct sets $\{T^k(x_n) \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and so since $X$ is Hausdorff these sequences have at most $N$ limits. So $x \in X_{\leq N}$ and so $X_{\leq N}$ is closed.